# Label back color change as ready state. VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, label

I have a windows form application, and I'd like to create two state a "process" indicator.
I'd like to use a label to indicate when a sub or function is running or not, with background color (green, red) and displayed text ("OK", "...").

This is a simplified code below. 
The "indicator" Label control named "`Label1`".
I have some functions and subs similar as "`GridRefresh`".

At the beginning of the sub I'd like to set the Label to red, and the end I'd like to set it to green.

My problem is that, the label never switch to red.
For examlpe the `GridRefresh` runs for 500-1000ms.
I've tried to put 2000ms sleep in the `If Then Else`, but nothing changed.

```
Sub GridRefresh()
    ReadySwitch(False)

    '--do something
    ....

    ReadySwitch(True)
End Sub


Sub ReadySwitch(ready As Boolean)

    If ready Then
        Label1.BackColor = Color.LightGreen
        Label1.Text = "OK"
    Else
        Label1.BackColor = Color.Red
        Label1.Text = "..."
    End If

End Sub
```

I've tried with multi threading also, but same effect.

```
Sub GridRefresh()
    ReadySwitch(False)

    '--do something
    ....

    ReadySwitch(True)
End Sub


Sub ReadySwitch(ready As Boolean)
    LabelReadyCall(ready)
End Sub

Public t1 As System.Threading.Thread
Sub LabelReadyCall(ByVal ready As Boolean)
    t1 = New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf Me.LabelReadyExecute)
    t1.Start(ready)
End Sub


Private Delegate Sub LabelReadyDelegate(ByVal ready As Boolean)

Sub LabelReadyExecute(ByVal ready As Boolean)
    If Label1.InvokeRequired Then
        Debug.Print("InvokeRequired - state: " & ready )
        Label1.BeginInvoke(New LabelReadyDelegate(AddressOf LabelReadyExecute), New Object() {ready})
    Else
        If ready Then

            Label1.BackColor = Color.LightGreen
            Label1.Text = "OK"
        Else
            Label1.BackColor = Color.Red
            Label1.Text = "..."
        End If
        Debug.Print("LabelChange - state: " & ready )
        Debug.Print("LabelChange - color: " & Label1.BackColor )
    End If
End Sub
```

In this case the content of the output window is this:

> ```
> InvokeRequired - state: False
> InvokeRequired - state: True
> LabelChange - state: False
> LabelChange - color: Red
> LabelChange - state: True
> LabelChange - color: LightGreen
> ```

What do I wrong?

Comment: If your using multithreading you need to an `invoke` otherwise in a single thread just after change the state try to use: `Application.DoEvents()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For multi threading you could try something like this:

```
Delegate Sub SetLabel1TextInvoker(ByVal TextToDisplay As String, ByVal colour As Color)
Public Sub SetLabel1Text(ByVal TextToDisplay As String, ByVal colour As Color)
    If Label1.InvokeRequired Then
        Label1.Invoke(New SetLabel1TextInvoker(AddressOf SetLabel1Text), New Object() {TextToDisplay, colour})
    Else
        Label1.Text = TextToDisplay
        Label1.BackColor = colour
    End If
End Sub
```

Then in your ReadySwitch function do this:

```
Sub ReadySwitch(ready As Boolean)
    If ready = true Then
        SetLabel1Text("Ok", Color.DarkGreen)
    Else
        SetLabel1Text(". . .", Color.DarkRed)
    End If
End Sub
```

If you are in a single thread application you could try to use:

```
Application.DoEvents()
```

Which will force the application to show the update on the label. The best would still be to use multi-threaded operations but if your a beginner this solution could be simpler

Comment: Thank you the try, but same result :/

Comment: I have to say Im a beginner, so multi threading is new for me.
I have to end somewhere the thread or something?

Comment: whats the problem exactly when you run my code? I use it in my software to update labels while going through thousands of files and it works. Just put the code i gave you and then add  `ReadySwitch(False)` and beginning of your sub and  `ReadySwitch(True)` at the end. But this works only if your sub is in a new thread like background worker. if you have just one thread add: `Application.DoEvents()` just after `SetLabel1Text` in your `ReadySwitch`

Comment: `Application.DoEvents()` _**SHOULD NOT**_ be used! @nobre : If you need to use it you're doing something wrong.

Comment: @VisualVincent thats why I said its recommended to use multi-threading instead it's  lot cleaner and safer.

Comment: @norbre: [**Keeping your UI responsive and the dangers of DoEvents**](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jfoscoding/2005/08/06/keeping-your-ui-responsive-and-the-dangers-of-application-doevents/)

Comment: @Visual Vincent: Thank you, I'l check it